# is there anyway that I can get a list of all cli commands for a Cat4k switch?

Tags: catalyst, switching

looking for a way to get all the cli commands of the catalyst 4500 switch , is there anyway or any sites I need to refer?

Answer (score 0):

Below link provides information for understanding and using the Cisco IOS command-line interface (CLI) on the Catalyst 4500 series switch:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/catalyst-4500-series-switches/products-command-reference-list.html